# ServerSideRowModel - Row Grouping/Tree data: How can we add root level nodes programmatically?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We have a requirement with `ServerSideRowModel`.

We need to have groups at root level, which we should be able to add programmatically.
When we expand the root level groups, they should be able to load data from server - that seems possible with dataSource.getRows api.

You could think of this as this example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-grouping/#example-row-grouping, when we expand any country, the data are loaded from server.
What difference we need is the countries (root level rows) should be loaded programmatically later on.

For example, let's say that initially we have only United States and Russia as the root level countries. Later, if I need, I will also add Australia, Canada, Norway in the grid. (adding root level nodes programatically)

Is this possible? The challenge I am facing right now is with ServerSideRowModel, the rowData are not accessible.

Comment: have you looked into this example - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-crud/#crud